# Eeny, meeny, miny, moe

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

## Introduction

The childhood song *Eeny, meeny, miny, moe* was often used to select who was "it" when playing tag.  Everyone would stand in a circle and point at one person selected at random.  They would sing:

> Eeny, meeny, miny, moe,
>   Catch a tiger by the toe.
>   If he hollers, let him go,
>   Eeny, meeny, miny, moe.

As they sung each word, they pointed at the next person in the circle.  The person being pointed to when the final "moe" was sung would be "it".  The children would immediately stand up and scatter.

## Goal

Implement the shortest program in bytes that takes an input, the number of children, and lists the words that were sung when they were being pointed at.

The winner will be selected in one week.

## Input

From STDIN, a single, positive integer, the number of children.  This may be more than the number of words in the song.

## Output

Writes to STDOUT a list where each line represents a child and contains the word sung while they were being pointed at.  If there are too many children, empty lines may be omitted.

## Requirements

- Always start with the first child.
- Display the words without punctuation.
- The final "moe" should be emphasised as "MOE!" including punctuation.

## Example

### Input

```
3
```

### Output

```
Eeny moe tiger toe hollers go miny
meeny Catch by If let Eeny MOE!
miny a the he him meeny
```

### Input

```
7
```

### Output

```
Eeny by him
meeny the go
miny toe Eeny
moe If meeny
Catch he miny
a hollers MOE!
tiger let
```

### Input

```
1
```

### Output

```
Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny MOE!
```

### Input

```
21
```

### Output

```
Eeny
meeny
miny
moe
Catch
a
tiger
by
the
toe
If
he
hollers
let
him
go
Eeny
meeny
miny
MOE!
```

Comment: Will the input ever be greater than the number of words present?

Comment: @Doorknob, yes, but empty lines may be omitted.  I've now clarified that.  Thanks!

Comment: Should "catch a" and "if he" and "by his"/"by the" be treated as two words or one? In the song, they only count as one "point"

Comment: @Hand-E-Food is pythons input() method a form of STDIN? (Sorry I don't know these things)

Comment: @AshwinGupta yes, it is.

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ ok great thanks. Also, if I were to store each word In an array, would initializing a blank element as the first element in the array so indexing starts at 1 instead of 0 be considered an unfair loophole?

Comment: @AshwinGupta that would be fine. Loopholes are generally when you exploit  an ambiguity in a spec

Comment: @OldBunny2800, I did consider that but decided to make it one word per point.

Comment: Can you add more testcases?

Comment: Are trailing spaces acceptable?

Comment: We always ended with "My...mother...said...to...pick...the...very...best...one...and...you...are...IT!" That would be a cool bonus. Of course, the cheaters always dragged out the "you" and the "are" over several people...

Comment: @LegionMammal978, there's too many existing answers to add that restriction now, so go for it! :-)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot NOOO (Darth Vader voice)! You stole my line. I literally logged on to PPCG just to write that since I've been thinking about it for the past two days since I saw this.

Comment: Not so fun fact: Tiger used to be the N word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [TeaScript](http://github.com/vihanb/teascript), 82 bytes

```
D`${a="Ey Ú9y ·ny "}¶e C® a g by e e If  Ò@s ¤t m go ${a}MOE!`q.KαtΣj═)j╝
```

Decompress, chunk, transpose, join, output.

### Explanation

```
              // Implicit: x = input
D`...blah...` // Decompress "Eeny miny moe..."
q             // Split
Kα            // chunk into x-size blocks (α == x)
t             // Transpose
Σ             // Loop through lines
j═)             // Join with spaces
j╝            // Join with newline
```

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22D%60E%C2%81y%20%C3%9A9y%20%C2%B7ny%20%C2%B6e%20C%C2%85%C2%AE%20a%20%C2%93g%C2%80%20by%20%C2%90e%20%C2%91e%20If%20%C2%94%20%C2%97%C3%92@s%20%C2%A4t%20%C2%96m%20go%20E%C2%81y%20%C3%9A9y%20%C2%B7ny%20MOE!%60qK(x)t%CE%A3j%E2%95%90)j%E2%95%9D%22&inputs=%5B%223%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:true,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false%7D)

---

**Non-competing 81 byte**

The `α` wasn't getting chained `.` so I had to bug fix this

```
D`${a="Ey Ú9y ·ny "}¶e C® a g by e e If  Ò@s ¤t m go ${a}MOE!`qKαtΣj═)j╝
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>103</s> <s>89</s> 84 chars

*Saved 18 bytes with string compression, thanks to @Dennis and @FryAmTheEggman*
*Saved another byte thanks to @isaacg*

Warning: there are many unprintables in the code; use the links below to try it.

```
VQjd%Q>cs[J."@y)òÎ5O¹c×Ú"."@yæ\J}ÇZH66¥ÓÀD¸¶=ðÉ §J%ÔþÖúÅ="J"MOE!")\@N
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQjd%25Q%3Ecs[J.%22%40y%05%29%C3%B2%C3%8E5O%C2%89%12%C2%B9c%C3%97%C3%9A%22.%22%40y%0F%C3%A6%5C%1B%C2%99J%7D%C3%87ZH6%11%C2%89%C2%846%C2%A5%C3%93%1F%C3%80D%C2%B8%C2%B6%3D%C3%B0%C3%89%1B%09%C2%A7J%25%14%C3%94%C3%BE%10%C3%96%13%C3%BA%C3%85%3D%C2%92%22J%22MOE!%22%29%5C%40N&input=3&debug=0test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0) | [Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQjd%25Q%3Ecs[J.%22%40y%05%29%C3%B2%C3%8E5O%C2%89%12%C2%B9c%C3%97%C3%9A%22.%22%40y%0F%C3%A6%5C%1B%C2%99J%7D%C3%87ZH6%11%C2%89%C2%846%C2%A5%C3%93%1F%C3%80D%C2%B8%C2%B6%3D%C3%B0%C3%89%1B%09%C2%A7J%25%14%C3%94%C3%BE%10%C3%96%13%C3%BA%C3%85%3D%C2%92%22J%22MOE!%22%29%5C%40N&input=3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0)

Could probably be golfed. Suggestions welcome!

#### How it works

```
VQjd%Q>cs[J."..."."..."J"MOE!")\@N    Implicit: Q = eval(input)
VQ                                    For each item N in range 0...int(Q):
         [                    )        Create an array out of the following:
          J."..."                       Set J to this string, decompressed. ("Eeny@meeny@miny@")
                 ."..."                 This string, decompressed. ("moe@Catch@...let@him@go@")
                       J                J.
                        "MOE!"          "MOE!".
        s                              Join the array with the empty string.
       c                       \@      Split the result on "@".
      >                          N     Cut off the first N items.
    %Q                                 Take every Qth item.
  jd                                   Join with spaces.
```

Comment: Reusing `Eeny meeny miny` somehow should save a few bytes. Also, Pyth has two built-ins for (de)compression (`.Z` and `."`).

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, `."` saves 14 bytes!

Comment: Does Pyth use UTF-8 or something else? This is 89 chars but 123 bytes

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Pyth uses ISO 8859-1 by default, so each character is exactly one byte.

Comment: `FNQ` == `VQ`, by the way.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman How comes that `MOE!` is on the first line instead of the last one in your example?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks for the suggestions! This saves 4 bytes.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks, that saves another byte!

Answer (score 5):

## Jelly, 84 bytes

```
“£Dṡ“Ṙ©“Ė“¡Ḳ⁵“=U“¡Ẹ⁵“¡Ṇm“ȯf“ŀQ“ÞṖċ¥“ṅ_“Ẉ1“¡æḷ“¡ƒmxĠ“¡ṇƭEỤr“¡Þ¦»ṫ-2;;“MOE!”W¤sƓZj€⁶j⁷
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcwqNE4bmh4oCc4bmYwqnigJzEluKAnMKh4biy4oG14oCcPVXigJzCoeG6uOKBteKAnMKh4bmGbeKAnMivZuKAnMWAUeKAnMOe4bmWxIvCpeKAnOG5hV_igJzhuogx4oCcwqHDpuG4t-KAnMKhxpJteMSg4oCcwqHhuYfGrUXhu6Ry4oCcwqHDnsKmwrvhuastMjs74oCcTU9FIeKAnVfCpHPGk1pq4oKs4oG2auKBtw&input=Mw)

Comment: Compressing the string by hand was... entertaining. The score would be a lot better if Jelly had a *split at occurrences* function.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 167 bytes

```js
l=Array(n=+prompt()).fill``;`${s=`Eeny meeny miny `}moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go ${s}MOE!`.split` `.map((w,i)=>l[i%n]+=w+` `);alert(l.join`
`)
```

### Explanation

```js
l=Array(              // l = array of lines
  n=+prompt()         // n = input number
).fill``;             // initialise l as empty strings

`${s=`Eeny meeny miny `}moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go ${s}MOE!`

.split` `.map((w,i)=> // for each word w
  l[i%n]+=w+` `       // add it to the lines
);
alert(l.join`
`)                    // output the lines
```

Comment: Does ```l=Array(n).fill`` ``` not work for some reason?

Comment: @ETHproductions It works. I just forgot to shorten it somehow haha! Thanks.

Comment: @user81655 I love JS prompt() windows. They are just so fun. (I know that sounds crazy but I mean in comparison to every other language's console.out or equivalent print type expression)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>160</s> 157 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
unlines.map unwords.transpose.(`chunksOf`(["moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go","MOE!"]>>=words.("Eeny meeny miny "++)))
```

Prepend `"Eeny meeny miny "` to the other parts (`"moe Catch ..."` and `"MOE!"`), concatenate both strings, split into words, take chunks of required size, transpose and concatenate again into a single string.

@Mauris found 3 bytes by factoring out the common substring "Eeny meeny miny " and making `f` pointfree.

Comment: Maybe `s="Eeny meeny miny "` saves some bytes.

Comment: @Mauris: I tried, but it was longer.

Comment: @Mauris: ... oh no, it has the same length.

Comment: How about ``f=unlines.map unwords.transpose.(`chunksOf`(["moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go","MOE!"]>>=words.("Eeny meeny miny "++)))``

Comment: @Mauris: Nice. Once `f` is completely pointfree we can omit even the name.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 160 bytes

```ruby
puts (a=[*%w[Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny MOE!].each_slice(gets.to_i)])[0].zip(*a[1..-1]).map{|x|x*' '}
```

All my attempts at "compressing" the string have just made it longer. <s>Still trying...</s>

```ruby
puts                      # output to STDOUT...
(a=                       # assign this stuff to the variable a
 [*                       # convert to array...
  %w[blah blah]           # %w splits on spaces
  .each_slice(gets.to_i)  # split into slices of input number
 ]
)[0]                      # take the first element of a
.zip(*a[1..-1])           # zip it with the remaining elements
                          #   because transpose complains about ragged 2D arrays
.map{|x|x*' '}            # join all sub-arrays on space
                          #   puts automatically inserts newlines for us
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, <s>279</s> <s>278</s> <s>272</s> 173 bytes

(thanks to Mathias Ettinger who literally saved me **100+ BYTES!**)

```
s=" Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny moe!";w=s.split();i=input();i=int(i)
for z in range(i):W=w[z::i];print(" ".join(W))
```

If anyone has tips or sugestions I'd really appreciate them. Thanks!

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what the input represents.  It's not the line number to show, it's the number of children among which to divide the words.  Every line should be displayed.  In your code, `int(i)` should take the place of `3`, but there are other errors to fix after that.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food okay I believe it works as you specified now!

Comment: That looks better!  :-)  And if you want some golfing help, investigate the Modulo operator, usually written as `%`.  It's ideal for cyclic counters.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food ok thanks! I think I know what you are getting at. I am going to fix this up tomorrow. I think I can shave at least a couple bytes off.

Comment: A few points that serves both at best practices and help shorten the code: 1) `.split()` will split on blanks (space, newlines, tabs) 2) `range(0, x)` is best written as `range(x)` 3) have a look at slice notation: `w[0::3]` will return a list of every three words in `w`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger wow thanks! That's a lot of tips. Sadly, I won't be able to use any of these until later after school but I'll put thoes in here. I think you might have saved me like 5+ bytes at least.

Comment: The slice notation alone, if correctly done, can save you something like 100 bytes.

Comment: Oh, and 4) a semicolon at the end of a line is completely unnecessary and bad practice in python. (even though it can be used to put several statements on the same line for golfing purposes ;))

Comment: @MathiasEttinger woops, that was just habit from java. Good catch. Ill fix that now since its quick. I'll also fix the range ones. Then I gtg but thanks for these great tips they really help! (I learned quite alot of python from you just now)

Comment: So, for the slice notation, have a look at `for z in range(i): print(w[z::i])` and try to fiddle with it. And remove that space at the beginning of `s` it won't give you any good.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Fixed it! Thanks so much. Now I get the slicing stuff. Also got me to learn about the .join function for list printing.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>154</s> 147 bytes

**EDIT:** Thanks Joe Willis!

```
i=input()
s='Eeny meeny miny '
for j in range(i):print' '.join((s+'moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go '+s+'MOE!').split()[j::i])
```

This uses the trick that [0::n] prints the nth element of the list.

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/Vsgb9g)

Comment: Ouch. Well you just totally destroyed my answer. LOL. I'm going to try your tip later today about the print("\n"). What exactly does `::` operator do? Is that like for in loop?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 189 bytes:

```
a=prompt(),b=Array(a--).fill``,c=0;"Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny MOE!".split` `.map(v=>(b[c]+=v+' ',c+=c>a-1?-c:1));alert(b.join`\n`)
```

## Explanation:

```
a=prompt(), //Get the STDIN
b=Array(a--).fill``, //Make an array based on how many kids there are
c=0; //Start the iteration variable
"Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny MOE!"
.split` `.map(
    v=>(
        b[c] += v + ' ',
        c += c > a - 1 ? -c : 1
    )
);alert(b.join`\n`)
```

Comment: Your input method is correct, but the output method is not accepted. You can, however, wrap it all in a function, receiving the input as an argument. You can try the following: ```I=>(b=Array(I--).fill``,c=0,"Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny MOE!".split` `.forEach(v=>(b[c]+=v+' ',c+=c>I-1?-c:1)),b)```, which is 172 bytes long. It returns each line as an element in the array. I think this is acceptable.

Comment: By the way, if you use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`, you can save 3 bytes, reducing to 169 bytes. With a bit more of fiddling, this might actually be tweetable!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The question asks for input and output to be specifically through `STDIN` and `STDOUT` so I think it limits JavaScript answers to `prompt` and `alert` unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, I see. I will update the code when I get a chance. Thanks for informing me :-)

Comment: @user81655 You are correct. It should have an ```alert(b.join`<newline>`)``` at the end. But the damage can still be reduced with `.map()`, instead of `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>90</s> <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```
Uo mW{V=`EydÚ9yd·nyd` +`¶C®»dgdbydÈIfddÒ@sd¤tdmdgod{V}MOE!` qd f@Y%U¥W} m¸·
```

Lots of unprintables. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VW8gbVd7Vj1gRYF5ZNo5eWS3bnlkYCArYLaCQ4Wuu2STZ4BkYnlkyAKRgklmZJRkl9JAc2SkdGSWbWRnb2R7Vn1NT0UhYCBxZCBmQFklVaVXfSBtuLc=&input=Mw==)

#### How it works

```
              // Implicit: U = input
Uo mW{     }  // Create the range 0...U and map each item W to:
V=`...`       //  Set V to this string, decompressed. "Eenydmeenydmined"
+`...{V}MOE!` //  Concatenate it with this string, decompressed, with V inserted.
qd            //  Split at "d"s.
f@Y%U¥W       //  Filter to only the items where (index % U == W).
m¸            // Map each item by joining with spaces.
·             // Join the result with newlines.
```

I've tried compressing the string with different delimiters. The only thing more efficient than spaces would be a lowercase letter, but most of these  are already used, and thus, can't be used to split the string. Here's how much compression is achieved with the remaining ones:

```
space -> 69 bytes
c -> 66 (including a null byte)
d -> 65
j -> 69
k -> 69
p -> 68
q -> 69
s -> 61 (but there's an s in "hollers")
u -> 65
w -> 67
x -> 69
y -> 69
```

Currently I'm using `d`. It may be possible to save a byte with `s`, substituting some other letter in `hollers`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 154 bytes

```
StringRiffle[Thread@Partition[StringSplit@"Eeny meeny miny moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go Eeny meeny miny MOE!",#,#,1,""],"
"," "]&
```

Uses the split-chunk-transpose-join-output method of most of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 167 bytes/characters:

```
n=input('');s='Eeny meeny miny ';s=strsplit([s 'moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go ' s 'MOE!']);f=@fprintf;for i=1:n f('%s ',s{i:n:end});f('\n');end
```

## Explanation:

```
n=input('');             % Grab the input (number of children)
s='Eeny meeny miny ';    % Common string portion
% Build the full string and split into cell array at spaces
s=strsplit([s 'moe Catch a tiger by the toe If he hollers let him go ' s 'MOE!']);
f=@fprintf;              % Just a shorthand for later (only saves 1 char here)
for i=1:n                % Loop to the number of children
    f('%s ',s{i:n:end}); % Print each nth word, shifted by child
    f('\n');             % Start each child's words on a new line
end
```

Won't be winning any awards for the length of this one, but it was fun. :-)